# Ограничение регулярки

Tags: php

```
preg_match_all("/&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;<b>(Вербовщик:<\/b>.+<BR>)&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;/", $str, $name);
```

Инфа парсится из http://www.heroeswm.ru/clan_info.php?id=5555 вот таких вот страниц. Только переменная id, может изменятся. 
Почему оно берет инфу аж до конца строки таблицы?

Answer (score 1):

Просто по умолчанию регулярки работают в "жадном режиме". То есть ".+" стараются захватить как можно больше. Достаточно после плюса поставить знак вопроса, как он перестанет быть жадным и будет "хватать" по минимуму.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что регулярки по определению берут так много, как могут. Точнее, самое длинное из самых левых совпадений.

Ну, чтобы долго не возиться, исправьте просто

```
.+
```

на

```
.+?
```

Теперь оно будет искать самое короткое совпадение, что вам наверняка поможет.